# Instantiate VHDL in Verilog with generics containing std_logic

Tags: generics, vhdl, verilog

I am looking to replace some generic synchroniser code in a Verilog module ([for this reason](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/185100/cdc-synchonisation-primitives-for-an-altera-fpga)). The code a standard 2-flop synchroniser.

```
always @ (posedge clk_i or posedge rst)
begin
  if (rst)
    begin
      rx_sync_tmp <= 1'b1;
      rx_sync     <= 1'b1;
    end
  else
    begin
      rx_sync_tmp <= rx_i;
      rx_sync     <= rx_sync_tmp;
    end
end
```

The entity declaration in VHDL is also straightforward:

```
entity synchroniser_d_flip_flop_n is

    generic(
        NUM_STAGES          : natural   := 2;
        RESET_ACTIVE_STATE  : std_logic := '1';
        DEFAULT_AFTER_RESET : std_logic := '0'
    );

    port(
        clk_i       : in  std_logic;
        reset_i     : in  std_logic; 
      d_i           : in  std_logic;
        q_o         : out std_logic
    );

end synchroniser_d_flip_flop_n;
```

But if I attempt to instantiate this in verilog the obvious way:

```
synchroniser_d_flip_flop_n #(2, 1, 1) rx_sync_block(
    clk_i,
    rst, 
    rx_i,
    rx_sync
    );
```

Altera Quartus-II 15.0.2 gives the following error (target is MAX10):

```
Error (10517): VHDL type mismatch error at synchroniser_d_flip_flop.vhd(9): std_logic type does not match integer literal
Error (10517): VHDL type mismatch error at synchroniser_d_flip_flop.vhd(10): std_logic type does not match integer literal
```

That is, it appears not to accept 1 as std_logic.

Xilinx [seems to suggest](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/ism_r_mixed_lang_boundary_mapping_rules.htm) that VHDL generics containing std_logic are not possible to instantiate in Verilog:

> Generics (Parameters) Mapping Following VHDL generic types (and their
>   Verilog equivalents) are supported.
>
> ```
>  integer
>  real
>  string
>  boolean
> ```
>
> Note Any other generic type found on mixed language boundary is
>   considered an error.

---

### tl;dr

Is there a standard way to instantiate VHDL generics containing std_logic in a Verilog file?  If not, what might be suggested as a workaround?

Comment: Try creating your Verilog with boolean instead of integer where you have a single bit signal. It's likely that your tools can convert boolean to std_logic and back, but I'm not surprised it rejects integer.

Comment: Can't you do it with `1'b1` or `1'b0` rather than using 1, which represents an integer?

Comment: @Rusell comment makes it work for me.  I have accepted the more complete answer as it discusses standaridsation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard - you'll have to check your simulator docs. The Cadence docs say that "The LSB of the Verilog integer parameter is mapped to a single-bit std_logic generic". The relevant table rather unhelpfully refers to SV, but I'm pretty sure that this will also work for plain Verilog.

The MoldelSim/QuestaSim docs say that you can instantiate a VHDL design unit in Verilog or SV if "The generics are of type bit, bit_vector, integer, real, std_logic, std_logic_vector, vl_logic, vl_logic_vector, time, physical, enumeration, or string".

isim has always been a bit of a train wreck - are they still using it in Vivado? I'd rewrite the VHDL to take an integer generic if you're stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
synchroniser_d_flip_flop_n #(2, 4'd3, 4'd3) rx_sync_block(
    clk_i,
    rst, 
    rx_i,
    rx_sync
    );
```

`std_logic` can take any one of 9 enumerated values: `{U,X,0,1,Z,W,L,H,-}` so with `4'd3`, you're specifying the 3rd value in this list.  For logic 0, you'd pick `4'd2`.

Comment: Hey, I see this is your first answer. Can't say anything about the content but  you could maybe consider using `backticks` around your inline code ( \` your-inline-code-here\` ) , and to make code blocks (indent with four spaces) for whole lines of code, to make your answer more readable.